# How to run perl script in task scheduler?

Tags: perl, windows-task-scheduler

```
C:\Perl64\bin\perl.exe C:\work\perlscript\hello.pl > log.err 2>&1
```

It's not working. **Task getting executing but output not displaying **

Comment: Have you read [Redirecting Error Messages from Command Prompt](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/110930/redirecting-error-messages-from-command-prompt-stderr-stdout)? How do you know that the script is getting executed?

Comment: on scheduled time promt is opening, but script is not executing & even log file is not creating.

Comment: You will need to give more information as it's impossible to know from what you have said so far. Are you sure that the script runs correctly?

Comment: yes script is correct , it's running through command line. & generating output. I just want to know is there any way to run perl script to in task scheduler or i have to run it through batch file.

Comment: Add the contents of `hello.pl`.

Comment: Don't do the output redirection.  Instead, open a filehandle in the script and print to that filehandle.

Comment: @ikegami - Windows task manager does not work the same as *nix cron jobs.  Based on the tests I ran, the task manager window (which is not the cmd shell) will capture and display the output but doesn't create the file for the redirect.  However, I didn't test all possible setups when creating the scheduled task, so there might be a way to force it to create the file.  The better solution would be to have the script print to the file instead of redirecting STDOUT.

Comment: Sorry, I used the wrong word. 'task manager' eq 'task scheduler' which is specified in the subject.

Comment: @Ron Bergin, Oh, missed "task scheduler" in title. (The title shouldn't carry info not in the question!!!) Yes, if they entered a shell command somewhere that doesn't expect a shell command, it's not a mystery why it's not working! Maybe they could write a batch file that contains the shell command, and schedule that (or `cmd /c foo.bat`) instead.

Comment: Wrapping the command in a batch file does work.  Since the OP is also redirecting STDERR, output buffering should be turned off in the perl script to get the output in the proper order.